# Neat content transitions like in HTML5 bing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I saw recently a nice effect being previewed in Bing for IE9 and also for Safari 5. When you press enter on the search box, the search box moves nicely up towards the top of the page and the results fold up from the bottom. You can see it in action here... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYuLALX6aeI#at=69

My question is, how is this done and how can I do this? I hope you can understand my question.

Comment: Lemme fiddle a very simple one for you

Comment: This is typical Microsoft trickery to give the impression you need IE9 to do this while any other browser can do the same and, probably, better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic idea:

**JQuery:**

```
$('#go').click(function() {
    $('#form').animate({
        'height': '80px',
        'text-indent': '50px',
        'padding-top':'20px'
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 1500,
        complete:function(){
            $('html,body').css('overflow-y','visible');
        }
    });
    $('#results').show({
        type: 'slide',
        direction: 'up'
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 1500
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#form {
    background-color:blue;
    text-indent:300px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding-top:200px;
}

#results {
    background-color:yellow;
    display:none;
    height:700px;
}
body, html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="form">
    <input type="text" /> 
    <input type="button" id="go" value="go" />
</div>
<div id="results">Search results</div>
```

**Demo:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/hwAtU/

Comment: `duration:1500` implies 1500 milliseconds, or "a second and a half." If you want the animation to take 1 second, you'd put `duration:1000`, half a second = `duration:500` and so on

Answer (score 1):

They are all using CSS3 animation. I fiddled a very simple search box with animation [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EuWQq/)
Please use Chrome or Safari. Just type something and hit enter.

CSS

```
body{text-align:center; padding: 200px 0;-webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;}
#search{-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;}
#search:focus{-webkit-transform:scale(1.4);}
```

HTML

```
 <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." id="search"/>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){document.body.style.padding = "40px";}
}, false);
```

Using Javascript for positioning and animation is not a semantic code. CSS animation are way faster and smoother.

Comment: Ok so your fiddle is biased against IE **and** firefox?

Comment: you can update it with -moz- and -ms- if you like them. I really hate IE!

Comment: Better is a relative term. Alien's answer is more scalable and robust. @Mohsen's answer is what we'd all *rather* be doing but the Internet isn't quite ready. If you are building an intranet app and your browser will be pre-determined and constant, go for the CSS3. Keep in mind JQuery does much more than simply animate. You could use Alien's solution to trigger logging callbacks, fill in the search results div with an AJAX populated *search result* and a lot more. A truly savvy web developer would utilize both these ideas :)

Comment: Modern browsers are like color TVs. if you have color TV you watch the show in color. If don't no worries, watch it but in B&W. So if you have modern browser like IE10, Chrome or Safari enjoy cool animations but if don't, that's OK. Just use the site without animation. It's not good to force a user with IE6 on Windows XP on a PentiumIII get a very slow and annoying animation just because we want everyone have same experience.

Comment: @Mohsen I don't think it's so cut and dry. We're not talking about IE6 here. IE8 is used by a huge chunk of the Internet and doesn't support your solution at all. Sure we'd like to think of IE users as morons, but all too often employees at companies are stuck with IE because that's all their IT department will support, and they are not given admin rights to install any other browsers. So a top level sales executive with lots of buying power over your product is supposed to get a low quality web experience because he's not using his personal laptop at Starbucks with Chromium?

Comment: I agree. IE is important. Even when making good user experience for IE is a pain we (web developers) always did it. But "animation" is not something necessary for users. Look how Bing developers looked at it. They just give the animation experience to users with high end browsers. Google did the same(in G+). Not having animation doesn't hurt anyone.